# scala groupby and sum on Observable

Tags: scala

I am a scala beginner and I want to perform a simple `groupby` and `sum` over an `Observable`. For example:

```
val test = Observable.just(("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 5), ("b",3))
```

I would like to group by key and sum over the values so to have something like:

```
(a,3)
(b,8)
```

I am able to sum over all with `test.map(_._2).sum`,but not when performing a `groupby`

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Need a bit more context. Which implementation of Observable are you using? Can you show the code that works, and the code that you've attempted that didn't work. What happened with the code that didn't work, was there a compile error or some unexpected result?

Answer (score 3):

not the classes you are looking for clearly. i was rummaging around scala.react and reactivex.io, but how about this:

```
scala> val test999=Seq(("a",1),("a",16),("b",5),("a",9),("b",9),("c",90))
test999: Seq[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (a,16), (b,5), (a,9), (b,9), (c,90))

scala> test999
res12: Seq[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (a,16), (b,5), (a,9), (b,9), (c,90))

scala> test999.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
res13: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(b -> 14, a -> 26, c -> 90)
```

Comment: Isn't this just standard Scala collections? Why would it be an acceptable answer to a question asking about Observables?

Comment: like Angelo said, need the context

Answer (score 0):

Given that

> I am able to sum over all with test.map(_._2).sum,...

namely that it is possible to `map` onto `test`, consider applying `groupBy` to `test.toSeq`.